# Apartment entrance intercom

Tags: doorbell, phone-wiring

Does anyone know how an old apartment intercom with door unlocker works? When I open it I see 2 wire connected to it.

The way it works is very simple: if someone at the building entrance pushes my name on the button I can hear a buzzer. When I pick up the phone I can talk and I can push a button to release the door.

It seems everything is going through those 2 wires.

Using a voltmeter I can read 13v. And when I push the button it go to 0v.

Any one know more about how this works?

Comment: That sounds about right.  If you're a tenant, it's not for you to alter the building.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of varieties of these systems. The more modern ones work over phone lines, and a phone line (POTS) is just two wires.

- Intercom is actually a small computer with a directory of names
- Select a name and the intercom dials the phone number associated with that name, hopefully ringing a phone in the correct apartment
- When you answer the phone and press *a button on your phone*, the intercom detects that button via [DTMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-tone_multi-frequency_signaling) and triggers the latch to open the door (typically an electromagnet).

However, older systems may work differently - e.g., using separate buttons and wires to trigger the door opening mechanism instead of DTMF signaling.

Comment: I think the one at my apartment is less recent than the one you describe. I think each flat intercom has his own line. Anyway it's seems, as you describe, that signal is sent through phone line since there is only 2 wire. But which is strange, is that, current go from 12v DC to to 0v DC when someone ring or when I unlock the door. So I'm able to reproduce the door entrance by linking 2 wire with a relay, but I'm not able to detect when someone ring. I guess the ring as some kind of signal even if current seems to go to 0v. But what is this signal ? How I can catch it ?

Answer (score 0):

At the entrance, there are two components: an electronic strike which can be unlocked remotely by push-button, and a two-way intercom.  Each of these needs power and ground to work.  When a visitor pushes your button, it activates your intercom. When any resident pushes their remote, it releases the electronic strike to allow a visitor to enter.